# How to generate jacoco coverage in manual tests?

Tags: gradle, jacoco, wildfly-9

I have a web application running on wildfly 9 using gradle to build it, and I would like to get code coverage of manual tests, so I started using `jacoco` for doing so. What I have so far is this in my `build.gradle` file is this for starting java in debug mode:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.debug = true
    options.compilerArgs = ["-g"]
}
```

And this for defining jacoco reports

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}
```

However, it does not generate jacoco folder, I think I am missing some point or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of JaCoCo involves following steps:

- execution of instrumented code (no matter as manual or automated tests)
- generation of report

Information that you provide in the question - is about compilation of Java files and generation of report, but nothing about execution of JVM.

There are many ways to execute code with on-the-fly instrumentation depending on how JVM is started (Gradle/Maven/Ant plugins, etc.), but they all boil down to usage of [JaCoCo Java Agent](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) while starting JVM:

```
java -javaagent:jacocoagent.jar ...
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `jacocoTestReport` task is not wired into the `DAG` for a normal build. To run it you can call the following from command line

```
./gradlew test jacocoTestReport
```

If you want it to run every time the tests run (which I don't recommend) then you can wire it onto the `DAG` in your `build.gradle`

```
test.finalizedBy 'jacocoTestReport' // not perfect since it will run when test fails
```

Or perhaps

```
check.dependsOn 'jacocoTestReport' // 'build' task calls 'check' which calls 'test'
```